# Cannot read property "displayName" of null, React DevTools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, electron

I'm working with a boilerplate React + Redux + Electron project. Devtools worked fine while I was adding a bunch of components and working on the UI, but now it won't load and any time I try to load it I get an error in the console, initially telling me there's an Uncaught Type Error (#1 below), the second being a warning from React Devtools.

```
    Error#1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of null
            at getDisplayName (backend.js:9159)
            at getDataFiber (backend.js:9888)
            at enqueueMount (backend.js:10158)
            at mountFiber (backend.js:10246)
            at backend.js:10306
            at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
            at Object.walkTree (backend.js:10304)
            at backend.js:8534
            at <anonymous>:52:32
            at Array.map (<anonymous>)
        getDisplayName  @   backend.js:9159
        getDataFiber    @   backend.js:9888
        enqueueMount    @   backend.js:10158
        mountFiber  @   backend.js:10246
        (anonymous) @   backend.js:10306
        walkTree    @   backend.js:10304
        (anonymous) @   backend.js:8534
        (anonymous) @   VM117:52
        emit    @   VM117:51
        setupBackend    @   backend.js:8621
        module.exports  @   backend.js:8567
        (anonymous) @   backend.js:116
        g   @   backend.js:981
        EventEmitter.emit   @   backend.js:894
        (anonymous) @   backend.js:302
        (anonymous) @   backend.js:7619
        (anonymous) @   backend.js:7618
        _handleMessage  @   backend.js:7611
        listener    @   backend.js:92
        postMessage (async)     
        handleMessageFromDevtools   @   VM131 contentScript.js:20
        emit    @   /Users/.../.../Pro…ensions/event.js:19
        Port.ipcRenderer.on @   /Users/.../.../Pro…er/chrome-api.js:37
        emitTwo @   events.js:126
        emit    @   events.js:214
```

This is the second error that loads after the first.

```
Error #2
Warning: React DevTools encountered an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of null
    warningWithoutStack @   react-dom.development.js:506
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:9577
onCommitRoot    @   react-dom.development.js:9625
commitRoot  @   react-dom.development.js:17493
completeRoot    @   react-dom.development.js:18912
performWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js:18841
performWork @   react-dom.development.js:18749
performSyncWork @   react-dom.development.js:18723
requestWork @   react-dom.development.js:18592
scheduleWork    @   react-dom.development.js:18401
enqueueSetState @   react-dom.development.js:12313
module.exports../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState @   react.development.js:372
setTimeout  @   prices.jsx:51
setTimeout (async)      
networkRequest  @   prices.jsx:49
networkRequest  @   react-hot-loader.development.js:587
componentDidMount   @   prices.jsx:58
componentDidMount   @   react-hot-loader.development.js:577
commitLifeCycles    @   react-dom.development.js:15961
commitAllLifeCycles @   react-dom.development.js:17262
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:149
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   react-dom.development.js:199
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:256
commitRoot  @   react-dom.development.js:17458
completeRoot    @   react-dom.development.js:18912
performWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js:18841
performWork @   react-dom.development.js:18749
performSyncWork @   react-dom.development.js:18723
requestWork @   react-dom.development.js:18592
scheduleWork    @   react-dom.development.js:18401
scheduleRootUpdate  @   react-dom.development.js:19069
updateContainerAtExpirationTime @   react-dom.development.js:19097
updateContainer @   react-dom.development.js:19154
module.exports../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render   @   react-dom.development.js:19416
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:19556
unbatchedUpdates    @   react-dom.development.js:18952
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer    @   react-dom.development.js:19552
render  @   react-dom.development.js:19613
(anonymous) @   index.js:10
./app/index.js  @   renderer.dev.js:3492
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:724
fn  @   bootstrap:101
0   @   fetch.js:516
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:724
module.exports../app/Routes.js.Object.defineProperty.value  @   bootstrap:791
(anonymous) @   bootstrap:791
```

Code from relevant file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import routes from '../../constants/routes';
const axios = require('axios');
let binance_api  = require('../../config/cxns');
let UserInfo = require("../../config/UserInfo.js");



export const GlobalContext = React.createContext()
export const Consumer = GlobalContext.Consumer
const Provider = GlobalContext.Provider


var AccountBallance = function(ticker, value_in){
  this.ticker = ticker;
  this.value_in = value_in;
}


export default class GlobalInfo extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userInfo:'',
      loading: true,
      data: {
        accountInfo:'',
        binance:{
          balance_gtz:[],
          subtotal:''
        }
      }
    }
  }

  networkRequest(){
     // Remove setTimeout and replace with a networkRequest
     // setInterval(() =>{
     //
     // }, 10000)


     axios.get(("https://api.nomics.com/v1/exchange-markets/prices?key=")+UserInfo.UserInfo.Nomics.key+"&currency=BTC&exchange=binance")
       .then((response, error) => {
           console.log('res: ', response.data)
     })

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.getInfo()
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      })
    }, 3000)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      this.networkRequest()
  }

  getInfo = () => {
    binance_api.cxns.Binance2.accountInfo()
    .then((res) => {
      this.setState({data:{
        ...this.state.data,
        binance:{
          ...this.state.data.binance,
          accountInfo:res}
     }});
    })
    .then(async (error) => {
      binance_api.cxns.binance.balance((error, balances) => {

        if ( error ) return console.error(error);
        var gtz=[];
        for (var x in balances){
          if (balances[x].available > 0){
            gtz[x] = parseFloat(balances[x].available) + parseFloat(balances[x].onOrder);
          }
        }

        this.setState(
          {data:{
            ...this.state.data,
            binance:{
              ...this.state.data.binance,
              balance_gtz:gtz}
         }});
      });
    })
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <Provider value={this.state.data} >
        {this.state.loading ? "Loading..." : this.props.children}
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: in `getDisplayName()`, allow the input to be `string | null | undefined` and you can then go about figuring out why your name isn't showing up. Otherwise, I don't have enough information on what you're dealing with. Post some code if you need more in depth help

Comment: @TabsNotSpaces well, the functions being called by the chrome extension, so let me get out some code. I'll edit the post.